# populate listview from mysql after dismissing dialog

Tags: android, mysql, listview

Currently I have a fragment that contains a list view. It has an Add button that will spawn a custom dialog fragment where the user can input a string.

when the dialog is dismissed via the ok button the listview should automatically update to contain the new input.

As of now I have to click the add button and I can see in the background behind the dialog box that the list is updated. So the list is being populated only after the add button is clicked again. Ive tried to even somehow populate the listview from the dialog box but nothing is working. Notifydatasetchanged() didnt work and changeCursor(cursor) didnt work.

Here is what I think is where the problem is.

```
addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addButtonPressed();
                testToast();
                myDb.insertRow(name,Integer.toString(time));


                    populateListViewFromDB(rootView);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Updated " + name + time + updateListview,
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }});

   public void addButtonPressed(){
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        dialog_foods dialog1 = new dialog_foods();
        // dialog1.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "my_dialog");
        //dialog1.show(ft, "acknowledgements");
        dialog1.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
        //dialog1.show(ft, "acknoledgments");
        dialog1.show(fm, "acknowledgements");

        //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Add Button Pressed",
          //      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        i++;




    }



private void populateListViewFromDB(View root){

        Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();

        //Add others here.
        String [] fromFieldNames = new String[] {DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, DBAdapter.KEY_NAME};
        int[] toViewIDs = new int[] {R.id.mMainLabel, R.id.mCityLabel};
        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
        myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.list_cell, cursor, fromFieldNames,toViewIDs,0);

        foodsListView = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.mFoodListView);
        foodsListView.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

        //myCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        myCursorAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);


    }
```

And just in case I have added the rest of my code below.

Here is my fragment that contains the listview

```
public class foods_fragment extends Fragment implements dialog_foods.foodsDialogListener {
        Button addButton;
        Button deleteButton;
        int time;
        String name;
        boolean updateListview = false;

    int i;

    ListView foodsListView;
    //DB Stuff
    DBAdapter myDb;




        public static foods_fragment newInstance(){

            foods_fragment fragment = new foods_fragment();
            return fragment;
        }
    public foods_fragment(){


    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        //outState.putAll();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_foods, container, false);


        openDB();
        populateListViewFromDB(rootView);




        foodsListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mFoodListView);



/*
        foodsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            }
        });   */




        addButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mAddButton);

        deleteButton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mDeleteButton);

        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clearAll(rootView);

            }});

        addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addButtonPressed();
                testToast();
                myDb.insertRow(name,Integer.toString(time));

                 populateListViewFromDB(rootView);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Updated " + name + time + updateListview,
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }});






        return rootView;
    }

    public void addButtonPressed(){
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        dialog_foods dialog1 = new dialog_foods();
        // dialog1.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "my_dialog");
        //dialog1.show(ft, "acknowledgements");
        dialog1.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
        //dialog1.show(ft, "acknoledgments");
        dialog1.show(fm, "acknowledgements");

        //Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Add Button Pressed",
          //      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        i++;




    }





    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        closeDB();
    }

    private void openDB(){
        myDb = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
        myDb.open();

    }

    private void closeDB(){
        myDb.close();

    }

    public void clearAll(View root){

        myDb.deleteAll();

        populateListViewFromDB(root);
    }

    private void populateListViewFromDB(View root){

        Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();

        //Add others here.
        String [] fromFieldNames = new String[] {DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, DBAdapter.KEY_NAME};
        int[] toViewIDs = new int[] {R.id.mMainLabel, R.id.mCityLabel};
        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
        myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.layout.list_cell, cursor, fromFieldNames,toViewIDs,0);

        foodsListView = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.mFoodListView);
        foodsListView.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

        //myCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        myCursorAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);


    }






    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(2);
    }
    public void testToast(){
       // Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), time + " " + name,
         //       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void nameTimeSubmit(int time, String name, boolean updateListview) {
        this.time = time;
        this.name = name;
        this.updateListview = updateListview;


       // View view = getView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        //populateListViewFromDB(view);


    }
}
```

Here is my dialog fragment if you need to see this.

```
public class dialog_foods extends DialogFragment {

    private foodsDialogListener callback;

    public interface foodsDialogListener{
        public void nameTimeSubmit(int time, String name, boolean updateListview);
    }


    LayoutInflater inflater;
    View v;
    NumberPicker hour;
    NumberPicker min;
    NumberPicker sec;
    int time;
    EditText nameField;
    String name;
    boolean updateListview = false;




    @Override
    @NonNull
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_food, null);

        hour = (NumberPicker) v.findViewById(R.id.mHoursNumberPickerFoods);
        hour.setMaxValue(24);
        hour.setMinValue(0);
        hour.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
        min = (NumberPicker) v.findViewById(R.id.mMinutesNumberPickerFoods);
        min.setMaxValue(60);
        min.setMinValue(0);
        min.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
        sec = (NumberPicker) v.findViewById(R.id.mSecondsNumberPickerFoods);
        sec.setMaxValue(90);
        sec.setMinValue(0);
        sec.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
        nameField = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.mNameEditText);



        try{
            callback = (foodsDialogListener) getTargetFragment();
        } catch (ClassCastException e){
            throw new ClassCastException("calling Fragment must implement onTimeListener");
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setView(v).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                int hours = hour.getValue();
                int minutes = min.getValue();
                int seconds = sec.getValue();

                name =  nameField.getText().toString();

                time  = hours * 3600000 + minutes * 60000 + seconds * 1000;

                updateListview = true;
                callback.nameTimeSubmit(time, name, updateListview);


/*
                MainActivity main;
                main = (MainActivity)getActivity();
                main.time = time; */

              //  Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Time: " + time,
                //        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }





}
```